# NullPointerException in Java with no StackTrace for OpenJDK

Tags: java, jvm, stack-trace

In my organisation we are running our projects on **OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)**, java 8.

I am logging my error in a fashion shown below:

```
org.slf4j.Logger.error("ERROR in while processing data", e);
```

I have went through relevant articles regarding no stack trace for implicit expections(like NPE) and found running the command `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` in the JVM.

However, I have also read that this is a cause and solution for Hotspot JVM(By Oracle)

What is the solution for this in My JVM?

If it is `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`, please educate as to how and where to run this command.

Comment: Even if you have `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` enabled, the full stacktrace will be there for the first instance the exception was thrown. You just have to browse your logs to find the first occurrence. This flag is an optimization to prevent printing the same stacktrace over and over again, not to remove them completely.

Comment: Unless you explicitly downloaded an OpenJDK with a different JVM, it will use the Hotspot JVM. But `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` is not a command but an *option*. You specify it at startup, together will all other options.

Comment: @Holger Okay, so you mean at core OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode) is probably running on Hotspot.
How to specify it at startup? Is it at application level or JVM level(through cmd terminal)